# How to access the color attribute of a matplotlib histogram using gcf() or gca()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, histogram

I have a single figure, `fig`, in which I plot a histogram and a line. I can access the line  color by using `plt.gca().get_lines()[0].set_color("Green")`. How do I do the same thing, but for the histogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work as you want?

```py
plt.gca().get_children()[0].set_color("green")
```

Here is the full code I used and the result screenshot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randn(100)
plt.hist(data)
plt.gca().get_children()[0].set_color("green")
plt.show()
```

[image]